# Active directory one specific account locked out continuously

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003

one specific account locked out continuously, we have checked antivirus updation also scan no virus so please suggest 
Server Windows server 2003
client windows 7 pro

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of account lockouts in Active Directory is when a user uses their username/password for other services that authenticate with Active Directory. If the user then changes their password, the password stored in this other service no longer matches, and will often continue retrying to log in causing Active Directory to lock the account for too many attempts within a given time period.

If this is the case, it may be solved by tracking down what other devices/services the user has used their login on. This may be a large number of things ranging from enterprise applications to mobile devices (laptops, cell phones, tablets) trying to connect to email or wifi, or even other desktops with manually mapped network drives.